# TypeScript interfaces React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I use one of the two interfaces for the same object?
For example:

```
interface one {
  id: string
  color: string
}

interface two {
  id: string
  numb: number
}
```

I have an `Item` component that receives an `item` object. This object can be of type `one` or of type `two`. If I specify the type as follows, then an error appears:

```
const Item: React.FC<{ item: one | two }> = ({ item }) => {
//
}
```

Is there any solution in this case?

Comment: `an error appears` What does it say?

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with the code you posted as far as it goes. Gonna need a little more to work with.

Comment: Or you can extend them into a type using an or condition to make it look good. export type apiData = one | two

Answer (score 0):

Use extends

```
interface One {
    id: string;
    color: string;
}

interface Two {
    id: string;
    num: string;
}

interface Item extends One, Two {}

interface Props {
    item: Partial<Item>
}

const Item: React.FC<Props> = ({ item }) => {
///
}
```

Here's [a example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIhQbwFDL84AEwC5kBnMKUAcwG5d8EB7AGyalIqpDuwF9s2UJFiIUAFQDuTZDnwES5SjXryQAVwC2pDZoBG0egKHho8JMgCSkTcggAPSCEJk0GADTIpMzMeFmxZAAFKCYAB1c5fGAbUiC4KDBgOBYAHmsITQA+fkFmEApke2QAXmQACjDQiLjqsgBKUqzZBjwq8LIAOhjMzt1+IA)

Comment: This will mean that item must have both `color` *and* `num` properties. It can't have just one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a union type, you need to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it via a runtime test to use non-common properties.

For instance, in your example, you can use the existence of the `color` property:

```
const Item: React.FC<Props> = ({ item }) => {
  if ('color' in item) {
    // use other "one" properties
  }
}
```

If you're going this route, for clarity I recommend skipping interfaces and using a discriminated union:

```
type one = {
  type: 'one',
  id: string,
  color: string
}

type two = {
  type: 'two',
  id: string,
  numb: number
}

const Item: React.FC<{ item: one | two }> = ({ item }) => {
  if (one.type === 'one') {
    // now it's much more obvious you can use 'one' properties.
  } 
}
```

If you have a type you can't change, and you have a runtime test that is obvious to you that it determines the type of interface, but it's *not* obvious to the compiler, another thing you can do is a type guard:

```
function isOne(value: one | two): type is one {
  return listOfOnes.includes(value);
}

// ...

const Item: React.FC<Props> = ({item}) => {
  if (isOne(item)) {
    // type guard means you can use 'one' properties here...
  }
}
```